# Make Custom progressbar

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-animation, android-custom-view

I want to create custom progressbar like below image

[image]

in that every one second the black circle is being disappearing with red circle for that i have used below code, if i use frame by frame animation i required 60 images so instead of that i have used below code

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="oval" >
        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#e9a30f"
            android:endColor="#953308"
            android:gradientRadius="300"
            android:startColor="#923008"
            android:type="radial"
            android:useLevel="false" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1.0dip"
            android:color="#953308" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="4.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="6.0"
        android:useLevel="false" >
        <size
            android:height="48dp"
            android:width="48dp" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="#000000"
            android:endColor="#ffffffff"
            android:startColor="#000000"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1.0dip"
            android:color="#ffffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape
        android:bottom="1.0dp"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="4.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="6.0"
        android:top="1.0dp"
        android:useLevel="true" >
        <size
            android:height="48dp"
            android:width="48dp" />

        <solid android:color="#ff0000" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1.0dp"
            android:color="#ffffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

by doing this code the image is done like below

[image]

but here you can see that oval is looking big i want to put that oval into black cirlcle please any body help in xml